# in c# i want to pass a variable from one button1 to other button2

Tags: c#

I was trying to add 2 numbers by using a single text box (both the input and output must be specified in a single textbox).when I click on '+' button the data on the textbox1 should arise and and should enable the user to type a new number, those 2 numbers should be added and should be displayed when an '=' button is clicked

so my problem is:

if suppose if a button1 is clicked then a variable stored the value of that button1 and only displays that value when button2 is clicked

please help me in finding out

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a the code you are currently working with.

Comment: It is a little hard to give exact advice as it is unclear the context.  Is this a web application or a stand alone program?

Comment: Sounds like you have two `textbox` and two `buttons`.  The two `textbox` are numbers and the two `buttons` are `+` and `=`.  So if I understand right you want to Add the two numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value in a text field, when button 1 is clicked, the value from the text field must be extracted from the text field and saved somewhere.  This is done in the click event handler for the button.

Depending on what type of a program you are working in, the place you save the info may be different.  You may save this in a temporary variable, a database, the session, hidden field, or somewhere else, it just needs to be saved.

When button 2 is clicked, extract the value in the same way and save it somewhere.  If you have two values in the designated saved locations when you click the '=' button, use these values, add them together, and populate the text box with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need just a variable to store first number.Define it in the class level:

```
int firstNumber;
```

Then when you get your number from textBox1 store it in the firstNumber,for example in button one (+) click:

```
int temp;
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp)
{  
   firtNumber = temp;
   textBox1.Clear(); // or set visible or enabled to false
}
```

In `(=)` button:

```
int temp;
if(int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out temp)
{  
   label1.Text = String.Format("Result of {0} + {1} is : {2}",firstNumber, temp, firstnumber+temp);
}
```

Comment: If he is using a web form, this method may not retain the value between post backs unless "firtnumber" or "firstnumber" is saved somewhere like the session or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so one `textbox` that the user inputs a value into.  One they use the `+ button` the number disappears and they are able to put a second number in the `textbox`.  The problem is you wish to store the value in the `textbox` prior to clearing it.  This is easy, and should be handled in the `Event Handler` for the `+ button_click`.

```
private int value1;
private int value2;
private int total;

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out value1);
}

private void equalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out value2);
    total = value1 + value2;
    textbox1.Text = total.ToString();
}
```